# Complex foreach loop possible to shorten to linq?

Tags: linq, lambda

I have a cluttery piece of code that I would like to shorten using `Linq`. It's about the part in the `foreach()` loop that performs an additional grouping on the result set and builds a nested `Dictionary`.

Is this possible using a shorter `Linq` syntax?

```
        var q = from entity in this.Context.Entities
                join text in this.Context.Texts on new { ObjectType = 1, ObjectId = entity.EntityId} equals new { ObjectType = text.ObjectType, ObjectId = text.ObjectId}
        into texts
                select new {entity, texts};

        foreach (var result in q)
        {
            //Can this grouping be performed in the LINQ query above?
            var grouped = from tx in result.texts
                    group tx by tx.Language
                    into langGroup
                    select new
                               {
                                   langGroup.Key,
                                   langGroup
                               };
            //End grouping

            var byLanguage = grouped.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.langGroup.ToDictionary(y => y.PropertyName, y => y.Text));

            result.f.Apply(x => x.Texts = byLanguage);
        }

        return q.Select(x => x.entity);
```

## Sideinfo:

What basically happens is that "texts" for every language and for every property for a certain objecttype (in this case hardcoded `1`) are selected and grouped by language. A dictionary of dictionaries is created for every language and then for every property.

`Entities` have a property called `Texts` (the dictionary of dictionaries). `Apply` is a custom extension method which looks like this:

```
    public static T Apply<T>(this T subject, Action<T> action)
    {
        action(subject);
        return subject;
    }
```

Comment: You can use `.Foreach` extension method to iterate over `yy` using lambda expression.

Also, I think it's better to perform grouping before `q.ToList();`.

Moreover, use *BETTER NAMING*!

Comment: You're right about the naming I was just puzzling and kept on writing lambdas that I went crazy on the entity, text and just wanted to type x, y, z :).

Comment: However, can the group linq query be performed inside the .ToDictionary somehow?

Comment: To clarify, your question is “How to write this LINQ code better?”, not “Hot to write LINQ instead of this `foreach`?”, right?

Comment: @svick: I would like to get the `foreach` part and the grouping which is performed to the LINQ query above the loop _or_ inside the `ToDictionary` which is below the `foreach`

Comment: I think what svick is at is this could be a question for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @ReFocus: I'm sorry, I can't recognize relation between entities in your sample. However, you can query on objects, like dictionary or any other IEnumerate. I recommend you to clean the area first. Before you use `.ToList`, wrap up your query and perform grouping, ordering, selecting and other operations. Then call `.ToList()`, this helps less connection to you Data Access Layer, and it means better performance. Also, it helps to bypass loops to process results in server memory, while you handled it well in your query.

Comment: @Reza: I changed the question with better naming... Can you elaborate? The entities are 'loosely' coupled as in the `Texts.ObjectId` and `Texts.ObjectType` are actually a combined key of some sort...

Comment: I don't understand your Apply method.  Why can't you just call the Action directly?  How is `result.f.Apply(x => x.Texts = byLanguage);` different than `result.f.Texts = byLanguage;`?

Comment: @cadrell0: The apply method is neccessary if the whole bunch would be done in a LINQ statement..

Comment: @ReFocus: do you realize that the operation that you want to do is extremely simple, and that it doesn't really need any Linq?

Comment: @d--b: Could you please tell me cause I think I'm overlooking something...? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isn't this far simpler?

```
foreach(var entity in Context.Entities)
{
   // Create the result dictionary.
   entity.Texts = new Dictionary<Language,Dictionary<PropertyName,Text>>();

   // loop through each text we want to classify
   foreach(var text in Context.Texts.Where(t => t.ObjectType == 1 
                                             && t.ObjectId == entity.ObjectId))
   {
       var language = text.Language;
       var property = text.PropertyName;

       // Create the sub-level dictionary, if required
       if (!entity.Texts.ContainsKey(language))
           entity.Texts[language] = new Dictionary<PropertyName,Text>();

       entity.Texts[language][property] = text;
   }
}
```

Sometimes good old foreach loops do the job much better.

Language, PropertyName and Text have no type in your code, so I named my types after the names...